# R: how to use lapply for monthly data

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a data set which has the below data:

```
Ticket      Feed back                            Date        Month             Rating
12345   The resolution was proper             01-01-2019    January              5
12346   The ticket was closed without notice  02-01-2019    January              3
12347   Good                                  03-01-2019    January              4
12354   He is highly reliable.                03-02-2019    February             4
12355   He accomplished all tasks             04-02-2019    February             4
```

I am implementing a sentimental analysis using the below code:

Negative words dictionary - https://gist.github.com/mkulakowski2/4289441

positive words dictionary - https://gist.github.com/mkulakowski2/4289437 
( created 2 txt files starting from line 36)

```
library(stringr)
library(tm)
str(positive)  #positive words dictionary
str(negative)  #negatiive words dictionary

file <- sample_reviews$`Feed back`
file <- tolower(file)
filee <- removeWords(file,stopwords("english"))
filee <- removePunctuation(filee)
filee <- stripWhitespace(filee)
filee <- removeNumbers(filee)
filr <- str_split(filee,pattern="\\s+")
fg <- unlist(str_split(filee,pattern="\\s+"))
match(fg,positive)
match(fg,negative) 
a<-sum(!is.na(match(fg,positive)))
b<-sum(!is.na(match(fg,negative)))
c<- a+b
Positiveperc <- (a/c)*100
Negativeperc <- (b/c)*100
mat<-matrix(c(Positiveperc,Negativeperc),ncol=1)
colnames(mat) <- c('values')
rownames(mat) <- c('Positive','Negative')
dat<- cbind("Result"=rownames(mat), mat)
mydata<-data.frame(dat)
```

Data frame in "mydata" variable looks like:

```
            Result       values
Positive   "Positive"   "57.785" 
Negative   "Negative"   "48.214"
```

I need my data frame to be created with respect to each month. 
As in:

```
 Month     ValuePostive    Valuenegative
 January        34              66
 February       50              50
```

with the current output im able to get an overall percentage of positive and negative words occurring.
What should i do to get this divided as a monthly percentage graph? like for each month, i need the percentage of positive and negative sentiments.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to divide. Do you want to get a different plot per month or one plot with data per month? Unfortunately, your it's not possible to reproduce what you want to do, as for instance we do not know what your positive or negative datasets are. Please provide the dataframe used to create your plot - what comes before isn't necessarily useful in this context.

Comment: @alex_555 I've attached the out put picture. Ive added the data frame data as well. what i want to do is to get the percentile value of positive and negative for every month.

Comment: Then you first need to get the months into your dataframe. This means you need values for each month and keep your months in an extra column. After that you can either use `facet_wrap()` or use `aes()` to specify how months should be represented. However, ggplot can`t plot what isn't there in the data.

Comment: @alex_555 I understand, I have a month column in my sample data. but im not sure how to drive it as expected. Made a few changes to the question to make it clearer. If you know how, please let me know.

Comment: Now I think I understood what you want to get. The problem is that your data-format isn't correct. Below I added an answer. Please tell me if adjustments are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you wanted to create:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(tm)

# your data
x <- tibble(Ticket = c(12345, 12346, 12347 ,12354, 12355),
            Feedback = c("The resolution was proper", "The ticket was closed without notice", "Good" ,"He is highly reliable.", "He accomplished all tasks"),
            Date = c("01-01-2019", "02-01-2019", "03-01-2019", "03-02-2019", "04-02-2019"),
            Month = c("January", "January", "January", "February", "February"),
            Rating = c(5,4,4,4,4))

# reading lists
negative <- read_tsv("negative.txt",col_names=F)$X1
positive <- read_tsv("positive.txt",col_names=F)$X1
str(positive)  #positive words dictionary
str(negative)  #negatiive words dictionary


sample_reviews <- x

# List-Conversion
sample_reviews <- split(sample_reviews, sample_reviews$Month)

# Your code executed for each month
x <- lapply(sample_reviews, function(x){

file <- x$Feedback
file <- tolower(file)
filee <- removeWords(file,stopwords("english"))
filee <- removePunctuation(filee)
filee <- stripWhitespace(filee)
filee <- removeNumbers(filee)
filr <- str_split(filee,pattern="\\s+")
fg <- unlist(str_split(filee,pattern="\\s+"))
match(fg,positive)
match(fg,negative) 
a<-sum(!is.na(match(fg,positive)))
b<-sum(!is.na(match(fg,negative)))
c<- a+b
Positiveperc <- (a/c)*100
Negativeperc <- (b/c)*100
mat<-matrix(c(Positiveperc,Negativeperc),ncol=1)
colnames(mat) <- c('values')
rownames(mat) <- c('Positive','Negative')
dat<- cbind("Result"=rownames(mat), mat)
mydata<-data.frame(dat)

return(mydata)
})

# Add month as column
x <- lapply(names(x), function(names){
  x[[names]]$Month <- names
  return(x[[names]])
})

# transformation for plotting
x <- x %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels=c("January", "February"))) 

# plotting everything in the same plot
plot <- ggplot(x, aes(Result, values, fill=Month))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())

# show plot
plot

# adding a wrap, which creates different plots based on Month
plot + facet_wrap(~Month)
```

This is what you get when using the first option:
[image]

And this is what you get adding `facet_wrap()`:
[image]

Is that what you want to produce?

Comment: I get this but my raw data is in a different form. as i see, you are reading the data from the output i am looking to get. I have a month column in my sample data, with which i need to perform the sentiment analysis. how do I convert my raw data after my sentiment analysis to the dataframe of what ive mentioned? The outcome you show is what i want to produce, but the data input is different.

Comment: The problem is, I can't use your original data from above, since you are using variables that are not specified (e.g. positive). I can't run your code completely as long as there are things that create errors.

Comment: I understand, the positive and negative are simply text files with positive words and negative words. added links in the question.

Comment: Ok, but your example is still lacking the packages you're using. Where can I `removeWords`, `removePunctuation` and others derive from? It would be a much better idea to use `dput()` of your dataset at the point you're stuck. Then I don't have to execute all the code that already works and I don't have to search for these functions.

Comment: Ive added the details of packages. I believe that using dput might not help us here since the data is getting changed in all the steps and i want to restrict its process to be performed for each month rather than on the whole data. My expectation is how we apply lapply() on different columns to perform the same operation. is there something possible for rows? since my month values are in rows of a single column. @alex_555

Comment: I've updated my answer using your original data showing how the conversion for each month works using `lapply()`. Is this what you wanted?